# Hibernate: Switched HQL query to SQL query, throws exception: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

In My `DaoImpl` class I am trying to fetch list of data of Type TBatchEntry(model class)

```
@Override
public List<TBatchEntry> getBatchListFormQuery(String batchNo) {

    session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    List<TBatchEntry> batchListFromQuery = new ArrayList<TBatchEntry>();
    try {           
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        batchListFromQuery =  session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM pghms.t_batchentry WHERE t_regNo LIKE '2008%'").list(); 
        tx .commit();           
    }catch(Exception e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();            
    }
    return batchListFromQuery;
}
```

In my Controller class I am trying to print value but it is throwing error in commented line:

```
List<TBatchEntry> batchListFromQuery = new ArrayList<TBatchEntry>();

try{
        batchListFromQuery = adminService.getBatchListFormQuery(batchNo);
 }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
Iterator its = batchListFromQuery.iterator();
    while(its.hasNext()){
        batchFromQuery = (TBatchEntry) its.next();  //This line thorws error
        System.out.println(batchFromQuery.getName());
    }
```

This is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_batchEntry")
public class TBatchEntry {

  @Id
  @Column(name="t_regNo")
  private String regNo;
  @Column(name="t_name")
  private String name;

  public String getRegNo() {
    return regNo;
  }
  public void setRegNo(String regNo) {
    this.regNo = regNo;
  }
 public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

log of tomcat`root cause

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.sv.pghms.model.TBatchEntry
```

I'd be really thankful, if somebody could help me.

Comment: What error is thrown from which line?

Comment: Mostly the issue is you are returning something from the query that is not likely possible to cast into `List<Object[]>`

Comment: And what error it gives when you return `List<TBatchEntry>` ? It should work if you map your Entity properly

Comment: Previously I was doing HQL query. Then                      
 List<TBatchEntry> batchListFromQuery= new ArrayList<TBatchEntry>(); was working good. When I tried with SQL query then causing problem.  in mappins is same.
I have added my entity class. Please see that.

Comment: After reading some related issue in this site, I changed my Arraylist declaration to List<Object[]> batchListFromQuery = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way just change class name and where condition.It is working for me.
Hope so it will work for you.

```
List<Book> books = this.sf.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select * from Book where book_id > 3")
                         .addEntity(Book.class)
                          .list();
    for (Book book : books) {
        System.out.println("Book Names are :: " + book.getBookName());
    }
```

Comment: After watching a video on SQL query of Hibernate, I got my problem. I didn't add '.addEntity()' after query.
Thanks for your answer. It gave me surity that the problem was not adding '.addEntity()'.

Comment: @Sourov, If you got your solution.You can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are catching TBatchEntry into Object class.You can directly catch into TBatchEntry class.
Change Object[] into TBatchEntry Class, because you are selecting all columns from TBatchEntry table right, try below code i think it will work,

1) From Controller,

List batchListFromQuery = new ArrayList<>();
use foreach loop for displaying records

change return type as below :

```
    @Override
public List<TBatchEntry> getBatchListFormQuery(String batchNo) {
  session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    List<TBatchEntry> batchListFromQuery = new ArrayList<>();
    try {           
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        batchListFromQuery =  session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM pghms.t_batchentry WHERE t_regNo LIKE '2008%'").list(); 
        tx .commit();           
    }catch(Exception e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();            
    }
    return batchListFromQuery;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Actually directy catch into TBatchEntry class throws same error. I have tried this at first. Then reading some similar article from stackoverflow I changed it to Object[].

Comment: I tried the same thing into my project and it is working fine for me, it is not throwing any type of exceptions.

Comment: Dont use iterator , use foreach loop for displaying name.

Comment: I have also tried with foreach loop. Are you using SQL query ?

Comment: use addEntity(TBatchEntry.class)

Answer (score 0):

After some study I understood the difference between HQL & SQL query in hibernate.

```
List<TBatchEntry> batchListFromQuery = new ArrayList<TBatchEntry>();
```

In case of using HQL query:

```
batchListFromQuery = session.createQuery(sql).list()
```

In case of using SQL query:

```
batchListFromQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(TBatchEntry.class).list();
```

Difference is:

**.addEntity(TBatchEntry.class)**